# phonegap integrate aviary/adobe-creative-sdk-foundation sdk

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a native iOS app with `AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation` framework. I want to integrate this framework in phoneGap(am complete noob to phoneGap). I following this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/adobe-creative-sdk-foundation) and installed `com.phonegap.adobe-creative-sdk-foundation plugin`.

But am unaware how to open the aviary photo editor on a button click in phoneGap.

In iOS I have just called the followng method to open the editor:

```
-(void)setupEdit
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [[AdobeUXAuthManager sharedManager] setAuthenticationParametersWithClientID:@"5587f31263dc4f38b003dc0a5d9a2e5f" withClientSecret:@"81292c83-eec7-42df-be72-334cbc1d6828"];
    });

    AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *editorController = [[AdobeUXImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hulk.jpeg"]];
    [editorController setDelegate:self];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

How do I do the same in phoneGap? Where do I go from here after installing the plugin? Plus how to specify the plugin in config.xml?

Comment: could you solve this?